# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined in Chrome

Tags: c3.js

I am using c3 bar chart and this working fine in firefox and IE-Latest Release, 
But in chrome-48.X , I am getting this error-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined
```

Below this version this is working fine in chrome as well.

Due to this error, popup of the chart is not displaying.

My C3 veersion#0.4.10

Comment: Can you please create a plunker or show us the code that generate the chart ?

Comment: I am also experiencing this error in chrome on a code that used to work fine. Looks like there is [temp fix](https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/issues/1566)